# @aspnet/signalr Angular triggering signal function for testing

Tags: angular, signalr

I'm facing following problem in Angular and @aspnet/signalr: I can't trigger functions which are called when a SignalR has been received. I want this for test purpose so I can manipulate data local in frontend and trigger a signal.

I'm listening to functions like this in code:

```
public addUserChangeListener() {
  this.hubConnection.on('user/changed', user => {
  // Do awesome stuff here
  });
}
```

And here is how I added this function to my signal:

```
this.signalRService.startConnection();
this.signalRService.addUserChangeListener();
```

Then there is a initializing part for the service:

```
  public startConnection() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('/signalrtest')
        .build();

    this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => console.log('Connected'))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```

And here is the first problem: I'm trying to **do this offline** and so I can errors. I don't want to use the backend server at all. So SignalR service should work offline and I want to trigger the functions from other services or controllers.

How can I do this? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to use Signal-R if you only want to update **your** client-side.
You can achieve data sharing between any component by using RxJS

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService{
    public $data = new Subject<any>();

    constructor(injector: Injector) {
       super(injector);
    }

    public publishData(data: any) {
       this.$data.next(data);
    }

}
```

Then you can get updates from any component in your application 
by subscribing to the Subject as following:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
   this.getData()
}
private getData() {
   this.dataService.$data.subscribe(data => {
      // This will be hit every time the publishData method sends new data
   }
}
```

Comment: its not client to client... its in the same application (and browser tab). So still not possible?

Comment: @yadbo If you want to update your other components with new information/data, you should not use signal-r. You want to use a shared service, look up RxJS and BehaviourSubjects

Comment: I need signalR for my backend. It's all working fine. But for testing purpose I'd like to use it offline without a server. I want to "fake" the signal.

Comment: @yadbo i updated my answer with solution for offline data update to components, i hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest way is to have a wrapper for creating the hub, and mock that:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRHubConnectionGetterService {
    constructor() {}

    public getHubConnection(): HubConnection {
        return new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl('/signalrtest')
            .build();
}
```

This doesn’t need much testing. You can inject this in your main SignalRService:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
    constructor(private hubConnectionGetter: SignalRHubConnectionGetterService) {}

    public startConnection() {
        this.hubConnection = this.hubConnectionGetter.getHubConnection();
        this.hubConnection
            .start()
            .then(() => console.log('Connected'))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
}
```

When testing the `SignalRService`, you can easily insert a mock object instead of the real `SignalRHubConnectionGetterService`, which can trigger whichever events you need for testing.